# Calculating the total number of days from multiple date input

Tags: javascript, html, css, date

I am working on a site to calculate the number of days user has been staying at our place. I am taking into consideration that they may have had multiple period of stay with us. Thus, I would want to calculate the total number of days that they have indeed stayed with us from the multiple dates they have chosen.

However, my calculate button is not giving me the intended results. It was working fine with single period.

Here are my codes :

```js
      function calculateEmp() {
      var startDate1 = document.getElementById("startDate1").value;
      var endDate1 = document.getElementById("endDate1").value;
      var startDate2 = document.getElementById("startDate2").value;
      var endDate2 = document.getElementById("endDate2").value;
      var dvtextless60 = document.getElementById("dvtextless60");
      var dvtext61182 = document.getElementById("dvtext61182");
      var dvtextmore183 = document.getElementById("dvtextmore183");
      var Difference_In_Time1 = new Date(endDate1).getTime() - new Date(startDate1).getTime();
      var Difference_In_Days1 = Difference_In_Time / (1000 * 3600 * 24);
      var Difference_In_Time2 = new Date(endDate2).getTime() - new Date(startDate2).getTime();
      var Difference_In_Days2 = Difference_In_Time / (1000 * 3600 * 24);

      if (Difference_In_Days1 < 0 || Difference_In_Days2 < 0) { // negative total days (start date later than end date)
        document.getElementById("dvtextless0").style.display = "inline";
      } else if (Difference_In_Days1 > 0 && Difference_In_Days1 < 60 || Difference_In_Days2 > 0 && Difference_In_Days2 < 60) { // 0 < total days < 60
        document.getElementById("dvtextless60").style.display = "block";
      } else if (Difference_In_Days1 > 60 && Difference_In_Days1 <= 182 || Difference_In_Days2 > 60 && Difference_In_Days2 <= 182) { // 60 < total days < 182
        document.getElementById("dvtext61182").style.display = "block";
      } else if (Difference_In_Days1 > 182 || Difference_In_Days2 > 182) { // more than 182 days
        document.getElementById("dvtextmore183").style.display = "block";
      } else { //NaN (clicking Calculate without inputting dates)
        document.getElementById("dvtextNoStartDate").style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById("dvtextNoEndDate").style.display = "block";
      }

      document.getElementById("numofdays").innerHTML = "Total Stay : " + Difference_In_Days1 && Difference_In_Days2;
      document.getElementById("displaystartend1").innerHTML = getFormattedDate(startDate1) + " to " + getFormattedDate(endDate1);
      document.getElementById("displaystartend1").innerHTML = getFormattedDate(startDate2) + " to " + getFormattedDate(endDate2);

    }

    function showArrDepDate() { // when Yes selected
      document.getElementById("dvPPbtn").style.display = "block";
    }

     function addDate1() { // when Yes selected
      document.getElementById("addDate1").style.display = "block";
    }

    function calculateDate() {
      var startDate1 = document.getElementById("startDate1").value;
      var endDate1 = document.getElementById("endDate1").value;
      var startDate2 = document.getElementById("startDate2").value;
      var endDate2 = document.getElementById("endDate2").value;
      var arrDate = document.getElementById("arrDate").value;
      var depDate = document.getElementById("depDate").value;
      var endToDep_Days1 = new Date(depDate).getTime() - new Date(endDate1).getTime();
      var endToDep_Days2 = new Date(depDate).getTime() - new Date(endDate2).getTime();
      var arrToStart_Days1 = new Date(startDate1).getTime() - new Date(arrDate).getTime();
      var arrToStart_Days2 = new Date(startDate2).getTime() - new Date(arrDate).getTime();
      var emp = new Date(endDate1).getTime() - new Date(startDate1).getTime();
      var emp = new Date(endDate2).getTime() - new Date(startDate2).getTime();
      var totalInDays1 = (arrToStart_Days1 + endToDep_Days1 + emp) / (1000 * 3600 * 24);
      var totalInDays2 = (arrToStart_Days2 + endToDep_Days2 + emp) / (1000 * 3600 * 24);
        if (totalInDays1 < 60 || totalInDays2 < 60) {
        document.getElementById("dvtextless60").style.display = "block";
      } else if (totalInDays1 > 60 && totalInDays1 <= 182 || totalInDays2 > 60 && totalInDays2 <= 182) {
        document.getElementById("dvtext61182").style.display = "block";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("dvtextmore183").style.display = "block";
      }

      document.getElementById("numofdays").innerHTML = "Total Stay and Presence : " + Total_In_Days1 && Total_In_Days2;
      document.getElementById("displaystartend1").innerHTML = getFormattedDate(arrDate) + " to " + getFormattedDate(depDate);
    }

    function resetForm() {
      document.getElementById('rCalculator').reset();
      location.reload();
    }

    function getFormattedDate(d) {
      return d.substr(8, 2) + "/" + d.substr(5, 2) + "/" + d.substr(0, 4)
    }
```

```css
<style>
    body {
      font-family: Arial;
      padding: 20px;
      margin: 20px;
    }

    label {
      font-family: Arial;
    }

    input {
      font-family: Arial;
    }

    span {
      font-family: Arial;
    }

    .residencyResult {
      font-family: Arial;
    }
  </style>

<body>

  <h1>How long have you stayed here?</h1>
  <h2>When you start staying here<span style="color:red;">*</span></h2>
  <p style="color:red;">(from the latest to the earliest)</p>

  <form id="rCalculator">
    <pre>
<label><b>Start date of stay <span style="color:red;">*</span></b></label><br>
<input type="date" name="startDate" id="startDate" required/>
<small id="dvtextless0" style="display:none; color:red; font-family:Arial;">*Start date cannot be later than Last date.</small>
<small id="dvtextNoStartDate" style="display:none; color:red; font-family:Arial; font-size:13px;">*This field is required.</small>

<label><b>Last date of stay <span style="color:red;">*</span></b></label><br>
<input type="date" name="endDate" id="endDate" required/><br>
<small id="dvtextNoEndDate" style="display:none; color:red; font-family:Arial; font-size:13px;">*This field is required.</small>

<button type="button" id="add" onclick="addDate1();">Add</button>

<div class="addDate1" id="addDate1" style="display:none;">

<label><b>Start date of stay <span style="color:red;">*</span></b></label><br>
<input type="date" name="startDate" id="startDate" required/>
<small id="dvtextless0" style="display:none; color:red; font-family:Arial;">*Start date cannot be later than Last date.</small>
<small id="dvtextNoStartDate" style="display:none; color:red; font-family:Arial; font-size:13px;">*This field is required.</small>

<label><b>Last date of stay <span style="color:red;">*</span></b></label><br>
<input type="date" name="endDate" id="endDate" required/><br>
<small id="dvtextNoEndDate" style="display:none; color:red; font-family:Arial; font-size:13px;">*This field is required.</small>

</div>

<label for="Presence"><b>Were you physically present here before this?</b></label>

<input type="radio" value="Yes" name="radiobttn" id="Yes" style="font-family:Arial;" onclick="showArrDepDate();">Yes
<input type="radio" value="No" name="radiobttn" id="No" style="font-family:Arial;" onclick="calculateEmp();">No

<div class="physcialPresence" id="dvPPbtn" style="display:none;">

<label><b>Arrival Date <span style="color:red;">*</span></b></label><br>
<input type="date" name="arrDate" id="arrDate" required/>

<label><b>Departure Date <span style="color:red;">*</span></b></label><br>
<input type="date" name="depDate" id="depDate" required/>

</div>

<span id="numofdays"></span>

<span id="displaystartend1"></span>

<div class="residencyResult" id="dvtextless60" style="display:none; border:1px solid lightgray; border-radius:15px; padding:20px; background-color:#FFFAC7; margin:15px;">
<span style="font-size:18px"><b>Stay is too short</b></span>


</div>

<div class="residencyResult" id="dvtext61182" style="display:none; border:1px solid lightgray; border-radius:15px; padding:20px; background-color:#FFFAC7; margin:15px;">
<span style="font-size:18px"><b>This is still too short</b></span>


</div>

<div class="residencyResult" id="dvtextmore183" style="display:none; border:1px solid lightgray; border-radius:15px; padding:20px; background-color:#FFFAC7; margin:15px;">
<span style="font-size:18px"><b>Oh ok.. That's long enough</b></span>



</div>


<button type="button" id="calculate" onclick="calculateDate(); calculateEmp();">Calculate</button>   <button type="button" id="startover" onclick="resetForm();">Reset</button>
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Tax Residency Calculator</title>
```

Comment: I have one confusion : On clicking 'Add' button more than 1 time, it is not adding new layout for input the new start-date & end-date.

Comment: Do you only want to take dates for 2 times (after clicking `Add` button) ?

Comment: As of now, yes.. only for 2 times.. i do intend to add in more later on..

Answer (score 2):

Your current code is throwing some exceptions. Just a quick look shows that your selectors are incorrect, ID startDate1 doesn't exist, for example, and some other ones will fail as well. It seems like most of your problems might be related to how you're accessing the data, and you're not considering what happens if the data is not there, you might need to add some checks if the value is null, for example.

I'm not sure why you're using vanilla JavaScript, but a couple of things could help you out, like jQuery, and maybe Moment js for date handling.

I would suggest running this in a local, plain HTML document,  or in a sandbox-like jsfiddle, and pay attention to the errors, they will give you a good idea of what's failing.

I would suggest not to copy/paste all the time, you can get lost with classes and selectors that way.

**Edit 1:**

- Your code isincomplete, the HTML doesn't close your pre or your form tags.
- Your ids in the HTML are incorrect, both start and end dates are named startDate and endDate, but your JS is calling for startDate1, endDate1, startDate2, and endDate2. You need to change those names.
- your variables totalInDays1 and totalInDays2 doesn't match  what the JS is trying to access in your calculateDate function (Total_In_Days1 and Total_In_Days2)
- You're tying to access Difference_In_Time, but you only have Difference_In_Time1 and Difference_In_Time2, you need to change that in calculateEmp where you're defining Difference_In_Days1 and Difference_In_Days2.

After these fixes, your code stops throwing errors. I would review your implementation and make sure that you're accessing the right variables when you're doing your calculations.

It seems like your problem was that you copy your working code and make incomplete modifications. If you have a version of your working code we might be able to help you adapt it to multiple dates.

**Edit 2**
After further review, it seems like you also missed some other variable names like emp, which you're defining twice, it should be emp1 and emp2.

I would create a separate function that takes in two dates.

In any case, I did some changes to your function calculateDate trying not to change its current behavior, just plain old refactoring.

```js
function calculateEmp() {
  var startDate1 = document.getElementById("startDate1").value;
  var endDate1 = document.getElementById("endDate1").value;
  var startDate2 = document.getElementById("startDate2").value;
  var endDate2 = document.getElementById("endDate2").value;
  var dvtextless60 = document.getElementById("dvtextless60");
  var dvtext61182 = document.getElementById("dvtext61182");
  var dvtextmore183 = document.getElementById("dvtextmore183");
  var Difference_In_Time1 = new Date(endDate1).getTime() - new Date(startDate1).getTime();
  var Difference_In_Days1 = Difference_In_Time1 / (1000 * 3600 * 24);
  var Difference_In_Time2 = new Date(endDate2).getTime() - new Date(startDate2).getTime();
  var Difference_In_Days2 = Difference_In_Time2 / (1000 * 3600 * 24);

  if (Difference_In_Days1 < 0 || Difference_In_Days2 < 0) { // negative total days (start date later than end date)
    document.getElementById("dvtextless0").style.display = "inline";
  } else if (Difference_In_Days1 > 0 && Difference_In_Days1 < 60 || Difference_In_Days2 > 0 && Difference_In_Days2 < 60) { // 0 < total days < 60
    document.getElementById("dvtextless60").style.display = "block";
  } else if (Difference_In_Days1 > 60 && Difference_In_Days1 <= 182 || Difference_In_Days2 > 60 && Difference_In_Days2 <= 182) { // 60 < total days < 182
    document.getElementById("dvtext61182").style.display = "block";
  } else if (Difference_In_Days1 > 182 || Difference_In_Days2 > 182) { // more than 182 days
    document.getElementById("dvtextmore183").style.display = "block";
  } else { //NaN (clicking Calculate without inputting dates)
    document.getElementById("dvtextNoStartDate").style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById("dvtextNoEndDate").style.display = "block";
  }

  document.getElementById("numofdays").innerHTML = "Total Stay : " + Difference_In_Days1 && Difference_In_Days2;
  document.getElementById("displaystartend1").innerHTML = getFormattedDate(startDate1) + " to " + getFormattedDate(endDate1);
  document.getElementById("displaystartend1").innerHTML = getFormattedDate(startDate2) + " to " + getFormattedDate(endDate2);

}

function showArrDepDate() { // when Yes selected
  document.getElementById("dvPPbtn").style.display = "block";
}

function addDate1() { // when Yes selected
  document.getElementById("addDate1").style.display = "block";
}

function calculateDate() {
  var startDate1 = document.getElementById("startDate1").value;
  var endDate1 = document.getElementById("endDate1").value;  
  
  var startDate2 = document.getElementById("startDate2").value;
  var endDate2 = document.getElementById("endDate2").value;
  
  var arrDate = document.getElementById("arrDate").value;
  var depDate = document.getElementById("depDate").value;
  
  var depDateTime = new Date(depDate).getTime();
  console.log("depDateTime", depDateTime);
  
  var arrDateTime = new Date(arrDate).getTime();
  console.log("arrDateTime", arrDateTime);
  
  var startDate1Time = new Date(startDate1).getTime();
  console.log("startDate1Time", startDate1Time);
  
  var endDate1Time = new Date(endDate1).getTime();
  console.log("endDate1Time", endDate1Time);
  
  var startDate2Time = new Date(startDate2).getTime();
  console.log("startDate2Time", startDate2Time);
  
  var endDate2Time = new Date(endDate2).getTime();  
  console.log("endDate2Time", endDate2Time);  
  
  var endToDep_Days1 = depDateTime - endDate1Time;
  console.log("endToDep_Days1", endToDep_Days1);
  
  var arrToStart_Days1 = startDate1Time - arrDateTime;
  console.log("arrToStart_Days1", arrToStart_Days1);
  
  var arrToStart_Days2 = startDate2Time - arrDateTime;
  console.log("arrToStart_Days2", arrToStart_Days2);
  
  var endToDep_Days2 = depDateTime - endDate2Time;
  console.log("endToDep_Days2", endToDep_Days2);
  
  var emp1 = endDate1Time - startDate1Time;
  console.log("emp1", depDateTime);
  
  var emp2 = endDate2Time - startDate2Time;
  console.log("emp2", depDateTime);  
  
  var totalInDays1 = (arrToStart_Days1 + endToDep_Days1 + emp1) / (1000 * 3600 * 24);
  var totalInDays2 = (arrToStart_Days2 + endToDep_Days2 + emp2) / (1000 * 3600 * 24);
  
  if (totalInDays1 < 60 || totalInDays2 < 60) {
    document.getElementById("dvtextless60").style.display = "block";
  } else if (totalInDays1 > 60 && totalInDays1 <= 182 || totalInDays2 > 60 && totalInDays2 <= 182) {
    document.getElementById("dvtext61182").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("dvtextmore183").style.display = "block";
  }

  document.getElementById("numofdays").innerHTML = "Total Stay and Presence : " + (totalInDays1 + totalInDays2);
  document.getElementById("displaystartend1").innerHTML = getFormattedDate(arrDate) + " to " + getFormattedDate(depDate);
}

function resetForm() {
  document.getElementById('rCalculator').reset();
  location.reload();
}

function getFormattedDate(d) {
  return d.substr(8, 2) + "/" + d.substr(5, 2) + "/" + d.substr(0, 4)
}


function calculateTimeBetweenDates(startDate, encDate){
    var response = {
    ValidDate1: false,
    ValidDate2: false,
    
  };
}
```

```css
 body {
      font-family: Arial;
      padding: 20px;
      margin: 20px;
    }

    label {
      font-family: Arial;
    }

    input {
      font-family: Arial;
    }

    span {
      font-family: Arial;
    }

    .residencyResult {
      font-family: Arial;
    }
```

```html
<h1>How long have you stayed here?</h1>
<h2>When you start staying here<span style="color:red;">*</span></h2>
<p style="color:red;">(from the latest to the earliest)</p>

<form id="rCalculator">
        <label><b>Start date of stay <span style="color:red;">*</span></b></label>
        <br>
        <input type="date" name="startDate1" id="startDate1" required/>
        <small id="dvtextless0" style="display:none; color:red; font-family:Arial;">*Start date cannot be later than Last date.</small>
        <small id="dvtextNoStartDate" style="display:none; color:red; font-family:Arial; font-size:13px;">*This field is required.</small>

        <label><b>Last date of stay <span style="color:red;">*</span></b></label>
        <br>
        <input type="date" name="endDate1" id="endDate1" required/><br>
        <small id="dvtextNoEndDate" style="display:none; color:red; font-family:Arial; font-size:13px;">*This field is required.</small>
        <button type="button" id="add" onclick="addDate1();">Add</button>

        <div class="addDate1" id="addDate1" style="display:none;">
          <label><b>Start date of stay <span style="color:red;">*</span></b></label>
          <br>
          <input type="date" name="startDate2" id="startDate2" required/>
          <small id="dvtextless0" style="display:none; color:red; font-family:Arial;">*Start date cannot be later than Last date.</small>
          <small id="dvtextNoStartDate" style="display:none; color:red; font-family:Arial; font-size:13px;">*This field is required.</small>
          <label><b>Last date of stay <span style="color:red;">*</span></b></label>
          <br>
          <input type="date" name="endDate2" id="endDate2" required/><br>
          <small id="dvtextNoEndDate" style="display:none; color:red; font-family:Arial; font-size:13px;">*This field is required.</small>
        </div>

        <label for="Presence"><b>Were you physically present here before this?</b></label>
        <input type="radio" value="Yes" name="radiobttn" id="Yes" style="font-family:Arial;" onclick="showArrDepDate();">Yes
        <input type="radio" value="No" name="radiobttn" id="No" style="font-family:Arial;" onclick="calculateEmp();">No

        <div class="physcialPresence" id="dvPPbtn" style="display:none;">
          <label><b>Arrival Date <span style="color:red;">*</span></b></label>
          <br>
          <input type="date" name="arrDate" id="arrDate" required/>
          <label><b>Departure Date <span style="color:red;">*</span></b></label><br>
          <input type="date" name="depDate" id="depDate" required/>
        </div>

        <span id="numofdays"></span>

        <span id="displaystartend1"></span>

        <div class="residencyResult" id="dvtextless60" style="display:none; border:1px solid lightgray; border-radius:15px; padding:20px; background-color:#FFFAC7; margin:15px;">
          <span style="font-size:18px"><b>Stay is too short</b></span>
        </div>

        <div class="residencyResult" id="dvtext61182" style="display:none; border:1px solid lightgray; border-radius:15px; padding:20px; background-color:#FFFAC7; margin:15px;">
          <span style="font-size:18px"><b>This is still too short</b></span>
        </div>

        <div class="residencyResult" id="dvtextmore183" style="display:none; border:1px solid lightgray; border-radius:15px; padding:20px; background-color:#FFFAC7; margin:15px;">
          <span style="font-size:18px"><b>Oh ok.. That's long enough</b></span>
        </div>


        <button type="button" id="calculate" onclick="calculateDate(); calculateEmp();">Calculate</button>   <button type="button" id="startover" onclick="resetForm();">Reset</button>
</form>
```

After this, you can see in the logs that there are some things that are missing when your function is trying to calculate the days.

Comment: Saying "your code has issues, use some libraries" might be a useful comment but it's not an answer.

Comment: Thank you, @RobG.  Sometimes I find it difficult to identify the line between giving pointers and doing a code refactoring.  Would it be more beneficial to propose an alternate solution? Or would you treat this like a full code review breaking down all the errors? serious question.

Comment: Some questions aren't worth answering because they are unlikely to help others. There are many questions and answers on getting the difference between two dates, and others on various aspects of the OP's code. Lumping it all together in one big post just isn't helpful. I'd try to focus on the primary issue, explain the OP's issue and how to fix it. The rest is just poor coding.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below JS function which returns the total number of days between two dates.

```
//startDate  = '2021-05-01' YYYY-MM-DD;
//endDate    = '2021-06-02' YYYY-MM-DD;
function total_days(start_date, end_Date) {
    const diffInMs = new Date(endDate) - new Date(startDate);
    //Converting milliseconds to days
    return (diffInMs / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
}
```

Comment: There are already many questions and answers on finding the difference between two dates. This answer doesn't tell the OP what's wrong with their code or how this answer fixes it.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but he used a long way for calculating total days. That's why I give this solution to find days and sum all days to calculate total days.